# Sequelize send picture from blob

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Right now I create a new url based on rowid and stream the picture back using fs. Below is my code that works right now.

This saves the picture from the blob pulled from the database.

```
exports.picFileSave = function (name, data) {
    try{
        // Query the entry
        stats = fs.lstatSync(name);

        // Is it a directory?
        if (stats.isFile()) {
            //do nothing;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(name);
        wstream.write(data);
        wstream.end();
    }

};
```

This function gets the picture filename and sends it back

```
exports.getLocBg = function (rowid, callback) {
    var filename = "tmp/loc/" + rowid + ".png";
    try{
        // Query the entry
        stats = fs.lstatSync(filename);

        // Is it a directory?
        if (stats.isFile()) {
            callback(filename);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        locationdb.location
            .findOne({where: {id: rowid}})
            .then(function (locations) {
                var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                wstream.write(locations.locationBackground);
                wstream.end();
                callback(filename);
        });
    }

};
```

This is simply the route that connects the client to the server

```
app.get('/mobile/locations/locbg/:rowid', function (req, res) {

    var options = {
        root: "./",
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true

        }
      };

    var rowid = req.params.rowid;

    location.getLocBg(rowid, function (callback) {
        res.sendFile(callback, options, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(err.status).end();
            }
            else {
              console.log('Sent:', callback);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

I want to be able to simply pull the blob from the database and send the picture back without writing a file and sending that back. How would I go about this?

Comment: I'm currently facing exactly tha same challenge. Have you eventually found a way?

Comment: I didn't find a way at the time, though I would look into using fs function to write the file into memory and send it. Reason I was looking to avoid writing a file at the time was due to efficiency and disk usage.